# Precompiled Python OpenCV 2.4 for Linux

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am deploying my working Django website from Windows 7 to a Linux server. The problem is, the web application uses OpenCV 2.4 and pip could not search for indexes for OpenCV lower than 3.0 during the installation of perquisite packages.

I have created the dev Django app using Windows 7 OS where pre-built packages are readily available through Christoph Gohlke repository packages. I have googled for tutorials for OpenCV installation but all of them requires compiling the OpenCV to python which is not possible (I guess) because sudo command is restricted/disabled for each individual account in pythonanywhere and Heroku.

Additionally, I could not upgrade to OpenCV 3.0 since I am using SIFT algorithm.

I was wondering if there are same websites that provide binary files of python packages for Linux platform?

Comment: Your assumptions are wrong, you can compile OpenCV without python and you don't need root permissions for that.

Comment: Also SIFT algorithm exists in the OpenCv 3, it's just been moved more appropriately to the `opencv_contrib`. [Pull both](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) compile and you can have SIFT in cv3 too.

Comment: I have read the tutorial in http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html and its says to run the lines through sudo (root permission). I am not saying the SIFT algorithm was removed I just don't want to change the core of my website (which would take me longer time to do).

Comment: [OpenCV 2.4.9 is already installed for Python 2.7](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/4064/) in pythonanywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the info!